# Appending data into multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am writing PHP code around into Node.js and I have come to halt on part where program is dealing with multidimensional arrays.

In PHP I got this (removed for loop to simplify it):

```
$tables = [];
$left_over_array = [34, 35, 36, 37];
$round = 0;
$row = 0;
$tables['round_'.$round][$row][]=$left_over_array[0];
$tables['round_'.$round][$row][]=$left_over_array[1];
$tables['round_'.$round][$row+3][]=$left_over_array[0];
$tables['round_'.$round][$row+3][]=$left_over_array[1];
```

Edit: `$row` value is not in `0,1,2,3` but maybe in `0, 1, 10, 3, 12`order.

Outcome of PHP code would look something like this:

```
$tables = [
              'round_0'=>[
                  '0'=>[
                      0=>34,
                      1=>35
                  ],
                  '3'=>[
                      0=>36,
                      1=>37
                  ],
               ]
          ]
```

Later I need to access this data. When I have it in this structure I can simply do `$tables['round_0'][3][1]` to get value `36`

My question is, how to achieve same thing with Javascript? or should I instead use objects? and then how do I do same thing with object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```js
var tables = [];
var left_over_array = [34, 35, 36, 37];
var round = 0;
var row = 0;


tables['round_'+round] = []; //In JS initialization before assignment is important 

tables['round_'+round][row+3] = [
  left_over_array[0],
  left_over_array[1],
];

tables['round_'+round][row+10] = [
  left_over_array[3],
  left_over_array[1],
];


console.log(tables['round_0'][3][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript associative arrays have to be declared as objects, and the key have to exist before you try to put anything inside of it.

So, following my code, I prepared a loop from 0 to 9, then check if the specific round_{number} is undefined. If so, I set the key as an array, and just then I add the elements to it, similarly to the **[]** from php, but with the function **push()** from Javascript.

```js
var tables = [];
var left_over_array = [34, 35, 36, 37];

for (var round = 0; round < 10; round++) {
  if (tables['round_'+round] == undefined) {
    tables['round_'+round] = [];
  }
  tables['round_'+round].push([
    left_over_array[0],
    left_over_array[1],
  ]);
  tables['round_'+round].push([
    left_over_array[2],
    left_over_array[3],
  ]);
}

console.log(tables['round_0'][0][1]);
```

Comment: What if `$row` values doesn't come in order? I made mistake giving row values in 0,1,2 order. In reality, they might now come in 21,3,5,11 order.

Comment: What does that mean? That the left_over_array has 21 values assigned?